# How to generate a set of numbers consisting of a certain number of digits in C#?

Tags: c#, random

I have to generate a set of numbers consisting of 5 digits, as shown below. I tried to search some info about this but found nothing.

```
int playerId;

System.Random rand = new System.random();
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
     playerId = random.Next();
}
Console.Write($"Generating player ID: {playerId}");

// output example: Generating player ID:  1158453178
```

As a result, i got a set of numbers consisting of 10 digits. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe take a look at the documentation? There is an overload of the `Random.Next()` method that takes a max value: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=net-7.0#system-random-next(system-int32)

Comment: Each iteration of the `for` loop is overwriting the `playerId` variable, and only the last one is being output. Is that what you intend?

Comment: This seems like a player order shuffle. you need to be more specific. Are the random numbers bound to a certain limit? Number of players? Can random numbers repeat or do they have to be unique?

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing in your code is generating five different random numbers of 10 digits (`random.Next()` generates integers less than the integer maximum value, 2147483647) and printing the last one. If you want to generate a 5 digit random number, you can just use `random.Next(100000).ToString("D5")`, which will generate a random positive integer under 100,000, and then fill out the front with zeroes if needed.

Answer (score 0):

you should put `Console.Write($"Generating player ID: {playerId}");` inside the for block, something like this:

```
int playerId;
System.Random rand = new System.random();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
  playerId = random.Next();
  Console.Write($"Generating player ID: {playerId}");
 }
```